# Spell Check for Properties file

Tags: properties, spell-checking

Is there any command line utility,to do spell check in english properties file.

For Example.

Properties file will contains like,

com.hello.world= Hello world.

com.module.home=hoem.

I need to find out wrong word "hoem"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On unix-like systems, you can use a combination of tools on the command line.  One example would be to use **egrep** to filter out lines starting with comment characters, **cut** to split the properties file on the equals sign and output the second field (right-hand side), and a pipe to a spell checker like **spell**.

Given this input file named resources.properties:

```
# Application resources
com.hello.world = Hello world.
com.module.home = hoem.
com.module.fruits = apple, bananananana, cranberry, grape, orange, strawburry
```

Here's an example of a command to spell check "resources.properties", and its output:

```
[user@host ~]$ egrep -v '^#' resources.properties | cut -d= -f2 | spell
bananananana
hoem
strawburry
```

The `egrep -v '^#'` command filters out comments (lines that start with the pound sign).  The `-d=` argument to the `cut` utility sets the field delimiter to the equals sign, and `-f2` directs the command to output the second field -- the right-hand side of the equals sign, a.k.a. the property value / string to spell-check.

On many systems, the "spell" command is provided by the [aspell](http://aspell.net/man-html/) utility.  An alternate command line that invokes aspell directly, and offers suggestions for spelling correction:

```
egrep -v '^#' resources.properties | cut -d= -f2 | aspell pipe
```